# MPU6050 on I2C is intermittently connected

Tags: python, i2c, mpu6050

I have several MPU6050 that will sometime show up in 'sudo i2cdetect -y 1' as 68.  When it is there my python code that reads them works.  Then randomly the code will fail to see the sensor, and when I run i2cdetect it returns all '--'.

Reboot doesn't change the situation.  Tried with multiple MPU6050s and 2 different raspberry pi's.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You ***seem*** to indicate that this intermittent error occurs across multiple combinations of RPi and MPU6050s. If that is indeed the situation, perhaps you should consider what hardware is common (wiring or cable???). Beyond that, your question doesn't provide enough details to formulate a reasonable answer.

Comment: Yes, intermittent error occurred across multiple combinations of RPi and MPU6050, but they were all from the same manufacture. (DaFuRui)  I purchased a different batch from another manufacture (FlashEagle) and have not had subsequent problems.

Comment: FYI: If your last comment was intended for me (it seems to be), please know that the **protocol** here in `Comments` for responding to a comment is a bit obscure. In this case, if you want to draw my attention to your comment, you would add my *"handle"* to your comment; i.e. `"@seamus Yes, intermittent ..."`. However, since I am commenting to **your** question (or answer), I do not need add it to mine. The comment still appears of course, but (in this case) I wouldn't necessarily be notified of the comment.

Comment: It seems that you have isolated the problem :)  If so, you might consider deleting your question. I make this suggestion because there are already several votes to close it based on the lack of details relevant to the question. If you'll notice, we get a lot of questions here that are either irrelevant to RPi, or impossible to answer. Please understand, we encourage questions, but they need to [meet the standards for "good" questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking a "good" question is hard - sometimes harder than answering!